# cocos2d iOS New Project Template

Tags: xcode5, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I get HelloWorldScene.h instead of HelloWorldLayer when I create a new project from cocos2d iOS template. How to get HelloWorldLayer? I'm using Xcode 5.5.1 and cocos2d 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 5.5.1, then nobody can help you because that would be under Apple Developer NDA (it is unreleased). If 5.5.1 is a typo maybe you are using 5.1.1 or 5.1?

in the HelloWork example, please look at `HelloWorkdScene.cpp` for:

```
Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    // 'scene' is an autorelease object
    auto scene = Scene::create();

    // 'layer' is an autorelease object
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();

    // add layer as a child to scene
    scene->addChild(layer);

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

There is your layer that is created and added to the scene. I'm not sure what you mean by `How to get HelloWorldLayer?`